# How to vertically line up DIVs with different heights

Tags: html, css

As you can see, I'm not best with CSS and I'm troubled to line up divs vertically middle.
I don't know what I should try anymore, so it must be something fundamentally wrong with my CSS.

FYI: I can't use label for input controls.

[You can get my fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nkje7xd7/4/)

```css
    .lbl-ctrl-unit{
        padding-top:2px;
        padding-bottom:2px;
        float:left;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        height:auto;
        clear:both;
    }
    .lbl-control{
        background-color:#D9EDF7;
        border: 1px solid #6FA7D1; 
        border-radius:5px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:3px;
        width:100px;
        display: inline-block ;
        height:auto;
    }
    .input-ctrl{
        display: inline-block ;
        position: relative;
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-right:2px;        
    }
    .btn-small{
        display: inline-block ;
        position: relative;
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-right:2px;        
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        /*background: url(../../images/plus_circle.png) no-repeat center center;*/
        background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat center center;
        cursor:pointer;
        border-radius:5px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .btn-small:hover{ border: 1px solid #6FA7D1;transition: all 0.5s; }

    input[type=text] { border: 1px solid #6FA7D1; outline:0; height:25px;  padding-left: 5px; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; transition: all 0.4s; border-radius:5px;float:left; }
    input[type=text]:hover{ background-color: #D9EDF7;}
    input[type=text]:focus { background-color: #D9EDF7;}
```

```html
    <div class="lbl-ctrl-unit">
        <div class="lbl-control">xxxx xxxx xxx xxx x:</div> 
        <div class="input-ctrl"><input type="text" id="txt1" style="width: 200px" readonly="readonly" /></div>
        <div class="btn-small" onclick="alert('You are clicking on me');"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="lbl-ctrl-unit">
        <div class="lbl-control">yyyyy yyyyy yyyyy yy y:</div> 
        <div class="input-ctrl"><input type="text" id="txt2" style="width: 200px" readonly="readonly" /></div>

    </div>

    <div class="lbl-ctrl-unit">
        <div id="strain" class="lbl-control">Strain:</div> 
        <div class="input-ctrl FocusSense"><input type="text" id="txtBactName" style="width: 270px"/></div>
    </div>
```

EDIT:

This is a layout I'm trying to set up:

[image]

Comment: can you post a picture of how you want them to be positioned? just take a screenshot and rearrange them in mspaint

Comment: @Banana I updated my question, sorry for delay, I was unable to answer right away

Comment: its alright. at least now its clear that you want to align them vertically, not horizontally :)

Comment: Oh boy! Don't tell this anyone its quite embarrassing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could align elements vertically if you set their positions to `inline`, the container's `line-height` to same value as its `height`, and then apply `vertical-align:middle` to the container:

also note the `white-space:nowrap;` that prevents the button from wrapping to a 2nd line in the container div, and since we removed the `block` from the button's position, you can stretch it to its size by applying a larger `padding-left` (remove it to see what happens)

```css
  .lbl-ctrl-unit {
      padding-top:2px;
      padding-bottom:2px;
      float:left;
      height:50px;
      line-height:50px;
      vertical-align:middle;
      white-space:nowrap;
  }

  .lbl-control {
      background-color:#D9EDF7;
      border: 1px solid #6FA7D1;
      border-radius:5px;
      font-family:Arial;
      font-size:12px;
      font-weight:bold;
      padding:3px;
      display: inline;
      height:auto;
  }
  .input-ctrl {
      display: inline;
      position: relative;
      padding-left:5px;
      padding-right:2px;
  }
  .btn-small {
      display: inline;
      position: relative;
      padding-left:25px;
      width:50px;
      height:25px;
      /*background: url(../../images/plus_circle.png) no-repeat center center;*/
      background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat center center;
      cursor:pointer;
      border-radius:5px;
      text-align:center;
  }
  .btn-small:hover {
      border: 1px solid #6FA7D1;
      transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  input[type=text] {
      border: 1px solid #6FA7D1;
      outline:0;
      height:25px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      font-family:Arial;
      font-size:12px;
      transition: all 0.4s;
      border-radius:5px;
  }
  input[type=text]:hover {
      background-color: #D9EDF7;
  }
  input[type=text]:focus {
      background-color: #D9EDF7;
  }
```

```html
<div class="lbl-ctrl-unit">
    <div class="lbl-control">xxxx xxxx xxx xxx x:</div>
    <div class="input-ctrl">
        <input type="text" id="txt1" style="width: 200px" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-small" onclick="alert('You are clicking on me');"></div>
</div>
<div class="lbl-ctrl-unit">
    <div class="lbl-control">yyyyy yyyyy yyyyy yy y:</div>
    <div class="input-ctrl">
        <input type="text" id="txt2" style="width: 200px" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

if you dont mind using CSS3, you can convert your containers to flex-boxes and set the child-textbox's margins to auto, it will center them as well:

```css
  .lbl-ctrl-unit {
      padding-top:2px;
      padding-bottom:2px;
      float:left;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      height:auto;
      clear:both;
      display:flex;
  }
  .lbl-control {
      background-color:#D9EDF7;
      border: 1px solid #6FA7D1;
      border-radius:5px;
      font-family:Arial;
      font-size:12px;
      font-weight:bold;
      padding:3px;
      width:100px;
      display: inline-block;
      height:auto;
  }
  .input-ctrl {
      margin:auto;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      padding-left:5px;
      padding-right:2px;
  }
  .btn-small {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      padding-left:5px;
      padding-right:2px;
      width:25px;
      height:25px;
      /*background: url(../../images/plus_circle.png) no-repeat center center;*/
      background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat center center;
      cursor:pointer;
      border-radius:5px;
      text-align:center;
  }
  .btn-small:hover {
      border: 1px solid #6FA7D1;
      transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  input[type=text] {
      border: 1px solid #6FA7D1;
      outline:0;
      height:25px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      font-family:Arial;
      font-size:12px;
      transition: all 0.4s;
      border-radius:5px;
      float:left;
  }
  input[type=text]:hover {
      background-color: #D9EDF7;
  }
  input[type=text]:focus {
      background-color: #D9EDF7;
  }
```

```html
<div class="lbl-ctrl-unit">
    <div class="lbl-control">xxxx xxxx xxx xxx x:</div>
    <div class="input-ctrl">
        <input type="text" id="txt1" style="width: 200px" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-small" onclick="alert('You are clicking on me');"></div>
</div>
<div class="lbl-ctrl-unit">
    <div class="lbl-control">yyyyy yyyyy yyyyy yy y:</div>
    <div class="input-ctrl">
        <input type="text" id="txt2" style="width: 200px" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lbl-ctrl-unit">
    <div id="strain" class="lbl-control">Strain:</div>
    <div class="input-ctrl FocusSense">
        <input type="text" id="txtBactName" style="width: 270px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a problem with that because your solution are continously shown in line (yeah I tried this) http://jsfiddle.net/x1b7utss/2/
and lbl-control is fixed width so high is variable.
This is mine version http://jsfiddle.net/kfpotcjp/
Thats my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#someid {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```